# d3 creating path for each object in array, instead of using each objects x and y properties

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

My very small and very simple data structure,

```
[{"x":0,"y":10},{"x":10,"y":35},{"x":20,"y":60}]
```

Now my draw function (no update pattern),

```
let lines = this.focus.selectAll('path.lines').data(this.data);

lines.enter().append("path").attr("class", "lines").attr("d", line)
```

Note this is an ES6 class, hence the this.data and this.focus (a layer in my svg).

D3 renders 3 path elements instead of a single path with 3 points using the x and y props!

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry thought the title was enough, have added to the question body aswell.

Answer (score 0):

yes when you do

```
let lines = this.focus.selectAll('path.lines').data(this.data);

lines.enter().append("path")
```

This will create as many paths as many data array elements are there.
Now you have 3 elements in the data array so 3 paths are generated.

It should be this way:

```
let myLine = this.focus.append("path").attr("class", "lines");
```

This will generate a single path.

Now add data points to this path, by passing the data points to the line function.

```
myLine.attr("d", line([{"x":0,"y":10},{"x":10,"y":35},{"x":20,"y":60}]))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: interesting i also found that by nesting the array so the structure was "[ [{"x":0,"y":10},{"x":10,"y":35},{"x":20,"y":60}] ]" it started to work.